# Find "IN" if array of ids is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wonder, is there any way to make the following code simpler?

```
  def my_filer model_names
      model_names.keep_if { |x| not x.empty? }
      unless model_names.empty?
        where 'model_name_field in (?)', model_names
      else
        self
      end
  end
```

Comment: what's wrong with how it is now?  Stack Overflow isn't for opinion-based questions/answers.  Specifically what are you looking for and what doesn't your example have?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Avoid using unless with an else branch. Generally unless is reserved for simple logic flow, or used at the end of the a line for conditional evaluation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. Probably it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def my_filter model_names
  model_names = model_names.to_a.select(&:present?)
  model_names.present? ? where( :model_name_field  => model_names) : self
end
```

**Note**: Rails converts the array value to `IN` statement when you use hash notation for `where` clause.

Comment: `#select!` and `#reject!` return `nil` if no changes were made to the array, which will cause this to throw an exception if nothing is stripped by `#select!`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald I am assuming that the input parameter value is non `nil` as indicated by the code in the question(i.e. `model_names.keep_if`).
The 2nd `nil` issue is addressed by using `blank?` instead of `empty?`

Comment: As edited, so long as the input is an enumerable, this should work great.

Comment: *Select! : If changes were made, it will return self, otherwise it returns nil.* if all are `present`, you will return `self` while you should be returning the `where`, am I wrong?

Comment: @oldergod, The method returns `self` if the value returned by  `select!` is blank.

Comment: @HarishShetty if all model_names are present, because there will be no change, `model_names.select!` will return `nil`. You will then have `nil.blank?` and return `self`.

Comment: @oldergod, you are right!(`select!` and `reject!` methods require document refreshers every-time) . I have updated the solution.

Comment: I have updated the answer to take care of `nil` input scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
def my_filer model_names
  model_names.reject!(&:empty?)
  if model_names.empty?
    self
  else
    where 'model_name_field in (?)', model_names
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is "simpler", but IMO, it's less readable. I'd suggest you use the more-verbose-and-easy-to-understand version, personally.

```
def my_filer(model_names)
  return self if (names = Array(model_names).reject(&:empty?)).empty?
  where 'model_name_field in (?)', names
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_filer model_names
  model_names.reject!(&:empty?)
  model_names.empty? ? self : where 'model_name_field in (?)', model_names
end
```

Not simpler, but a different form.

Or you could use the `&&` and `||` for expressing the ternary.

Perhaps less commonly used, is the `and` and `or` operators.